# Testing palindromes

Tags: ruby, testing, palindrome

I'm attempting to make a function in Ruby that tells if a string is a palindrome. I've checked over previous examples however I cannot find a solution that passes the tests that are ran on my code. The assignment starts us off with this bit of code.

```
def palindrome?(string)
  # your code here
end
```

And this is what I have made.

```
class String
  def palindrome?(string)
    y = string.downcase.scan(/\w/)
    if y == y.reverse
      puts "Palindrome"
    else
      puts "Not a palindrome"
    end
  end
end
```

And this is the results of the test ran against it.

```
Failure/Error: palindrome?("A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama").should be_true
NoMethodError:
undefined method `palindrome?' for 
#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x00000002c5e368>
 # ./spec.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./lib/rspec_runner.rb:36:in `block in run_rspec'
 # ./lib/rspec_runner.rb:32:in `run_rspec'
 # ./lib/rspec_runner.rb:23:in `run'
 # lib/graders/weighted_rspec_grader.rb:6:in `grade!'
  # ./grade:32:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Based on the nature and wording of the question and the presence of `grader` in your error I'm assuming this is a homework question, and have applied the tag appropriately. If I am wrong, please let me know.

Comment: The homework tag is now officially deprecated. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `palindrome?` as though it's a method on the current spec object, but you have monkeypatched it to be defined on String. Except that you have *also* defined the method to take a string argument.

As written, you would need to write:

```
str = "A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama"
str.palindrome?(str).should be_true
```

…except that you also don't return `true` from your method, you just `puts` a string. (And `puts` always returns `nil`, and so your method as written always returns `nil` as the result, whether there's a match or not.)

You could either change your code and the test to be a proper method on a string:

```
class String
  def palindrome?
    letters = self.downcase.scan(/\w/)
    letters == letters.reverse
  end
end    
"A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama".palindrome?.should be_true
```

…or you will have to make it a proper 'global' method:

```
def palindrome?(str)
  letters = str.downcase.scan(/\w/)
  letters == letters.reverse
end
palindrome?("A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama").should be_true
```

*Note that you're using `\w` which will match letters, numbers, and underscores; are you sure this is what you want?*

Comment: We are not allowed to alter the testing. However, the reason I monkeypatched it to be defined on string was because downcase and scan are properties of the class String. Is this not correct? Are there other ways to access those two methods without monkeypatching it? I'm still having trouble getting these tests to pass.

Comment: @herman5, `downcase` and `scan` are part of `String`'s public API. As long as you have access to the object, you can call public methods on it from any scope.

Comment: @Phrogz after a good night's rest your explanation makes a tremendous amount of sense. It's also quite easy to see what I was doing incorrectly. Looks like I won't be monkey wrenching String any longer :)

Comment: @herman5 Great! Glad to have helped, and welcome to the wonderful world of Ruby programming. ;)